# Firebase Query filtered by creation time and where date is greater than now

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I'm kinda new to Firebase and I'm trying to create an app with it.

My app has posts that are created at a certain time and they contain a certain time.

I store my data the following way :

```
"posts" : {
    "postid1" : {
      "author" : {
        "full_name" : "author1",
        "uid" : "idauthor1"
      },
      "date" : 1474455840809,
      "description" : "",
      "title" : "Test 1"
    },
    "postid2" : {
      "author" : {
        "full_name" : "author1",
        "uid" : "idauthor1"
      },
      "date" : 1480424400622,
      "description" : "",
      "title" : "Test 2"
    }
}
```

The `postID` is generated automatically so that should be enough to order them by creation time, but I also want to exclude the ones where the date is past today (*now*).

Does anyone have an idea how I could/should do that?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I suppose you are saving date with "ServerValue.Timestamp".

I think what you want to achieve is not possible directly because you should pass a date (today) as an argument, and you can't put ServerValue.Timestamp.

What I would do is to query all the posts this way: `ref.orderByChild("date")`

And then filtering in client-side.

**EDIT**
This should work. (it returns posts with date after today, local time)

```
query.orderByChild("date").startAt(new DateTime().getMillis())
```

Then you should order by key in client-side

Comment: Date is picked by the user when creating the post.

What I'm trying to do is order the list the key (which is creation date) and exclude the posts where date is past the local time

Comment: It does remove the ones that are over but now the list is order by date, and I still want it to be ordered by the time they where created (orderByKey())

Comment: It's not possible, you should order them in the client-side @Archipel

Comment: @Archipel if you think this answer is helpful, it would be great to mark it as the response.

Answer (score 3):

The query for that should be

```
// server_timestamp is a long type variable
ref.child("posts").orderByChild("date").startAt(server_timestamp);
```

The problem is (as mentioned by @Bonja) you can't pass Firebase's constant `ServerValue.TIMESTAMP`to that method.

So, you can either do this (**not recommended** because the time is based on user's device timezone and it might not synced correctly)

```
Long server_timestamp = new Date().getTime();
```

or my own hacky way (saving `ServerValue.TIMESTAMP` to a special node and then get the value. and yes, it's a lot of work to do)

```
ref.child("current_timestamp").setValue(ServerValue.TIMESTAMP, new DatabaseReference.CompletionListener() {
    @Override
    public void onComplete(DatabaseError databaseError, DatabaseReference databaseReference) {
        databaseReference.addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {
            @Override
            public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
                Long server_timestamp = dataSnapshot.getValue(Long.class);
                ref.child("posts").orderByChild("date").startAt(server_timestamp).addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
                        Post post = dataSnapshot.getValue(Post.class);
                    }

                    @Override
                    public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {}
                });
            }

            @Override
            public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {}
        });
    }
});
```

Hope this helps :)