# Unable to use .startAt() with datetime in milliseconds

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I have a very similar problem to this post -  [Firebase Query filtered by creation time and where date is greater than now](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39587428/firebase-query-filtered-by-creation-time-and-where-date-is-greater-than-now)

I have my dates stored in a "message" and I want to retrieve all messages after the current time.[image]

This query works:

```
Query myTopPostsQuery = mFirebaseDatabaseReference.child(MESSAGES_CHILD).orderByChild("time");
```

this query returns no data:

```
Query myTopPostsQuery = mFirebaseDatabaseReference.child(MESSAGES_CHILD).orderByChild("time").startAt(System.currentTimeMillis());
```

This seems like it should work but from [the docs](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/firebase.database.Query#startAt) I'm wondering if this is a data type problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your query, you need to specify the full path to the child used for ordering:

```
orderByChild("date/time")
```

You indicate that your first query works.  It may return the number of messages you expect, but if you look at them, you will find they are not ordered.  The query processing is forgiving.  If it doesn't find a value for the child identified by `orderByChild()`, it assigns a value of null and [orders by these rules](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/android/lists-of-data#data-order).